# What components and properties are required to implement a client only for oauth2 in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm currently tasked with creating a microservice running springboot that retrieves an oauth2 token to make further calls with. I've found an overwhelming amount of articles that implement it in different ways and cant seem to find a complete answer in any one of them. I have decided to start from scratch by making a project off of https://start.spring.io/ that has only the spring security and oauth2 dependencies. I have added the below to my properties file: (fake values substituted in for id's client names and secrets)

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myclient.client-id=clientidhere
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myclient.client-secret=clientsecrethere
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myclient.client-name=myclient
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myclient.provider=myclient
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myclient.scope=search.all
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myclient.redirect-uri-template="http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myclient.client-authentication-method=basic
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myclient.authorization-grant-type=CLIENT_CREDENTIALS
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.myclient.authorization-uri=https://someservername.com/oauth/auz/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.myclient.token-uri=https://someservername.com/oauth/oauth20/token
```

The documentation makes it sound like spring will see those properties and automatically set everything up for me.

Expected behavior: when I navigate to localhost:8080 it will now be behind spring security and oauth thereby retrieving my token. (possibly where Im going wrong if that assumption is wrong)

Actual behavior:

I get redirected to: http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/myclient (which I would expect)
I see this in my IDE terminal about 50 times:

```
2020-11-25 12:17:46.267 ERROR 31756 --- [io-8080-exec-10] OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter : Authorization Request failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Authorization Grant Type (CLIENT_CREDENTIALS) for Client Registration with Id: myclient
```

Can anyone provide some pointers on how I get this running to bring me back that oauth2 token?

Some additional facts:

1. I don't want to use reactive and override the WebClient unless it's my only option
2. Versions of security prior to 5.2.x seem to not support client_credentials grant types.
3. I can successfully retrieve the token using postman so I know it works
4. I don't want any auth server or resource server code. Just the client stuff
5. I am super new to spring security and oauth so if I've left out some critical detail just let me know and I'll get it added!

Comment: The Client Credentials grant flow is typically used when your backend application wants to talk to a REST API. However, the redirection you are describing is the Authorization Code grant flow. What do you need the token for?

Comment: The flow to my understanding of the design so far is that customers call my service and I call a service that handles both issuing a token for my service to make calls with and redirecting to the underlying source system with the data the customer is trying to retrieve. The client credentials grant flow is a part of the design given to me so I don't have flexibility in choosing another one. Unless it simply wont work and then I'll have to send it back to architecture.

Comment: As an additional comment both the service Im building and the service with the data are backend REST API's

Comment: Thanks, that's all very helpful. How do customers authenticate to your REST API? I also don't think I understand what you mean by "redirecting to the underlying source system". A chat might be helpful to get a better picture.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. So disregard the "redirect" I mentioned. Essentially I need to use a client credential grant that I get from an auth server to be able to make a second call to a resource server. I unfortunately can't get spring to get the token on startup of the service. Im considering using a resttemplate to try next. What do you use to chat with people? I'd be more than willing to if you think it will help!

Comment: another point here is that the customers calling me dont need the oauth token they are internal. It's the call my endpoints make to the resource server that needs to include it.

Comment: Actually, my apologies, I didn't realize that StackOverflow requires 20 reputation points to use their chat feature. Maybe you could ping me on https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-security - once I better understand your setup, I can give a more reasonable answer here.

Comment: I needed to test for awhile to make sure I was seeing everything correctly but my error was unrelated to oauth2 and more related to another security function the endpoint I was calling used. As a result I kept changing the oauth2 settings to 'fix' it and ended up in various states with oauth2 that didn't work. Thanks for trying to get in there and help @jzheaux but I think I was my own problem on this issue. It has been resolved now.

Comment: Great! Glad you found a solution.